# Angular ngbDropdown autoClose outside not working in version 4.1.3

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngbDropdown and have upgraded ng-bootstrap from version 3 to 4.1.3, and now [autoClose]="'outside'" is closing, no matter if I press inside or outside the dropdown :-| if I set it to false it's working like expected.

```
<span *ngIf="!isAllItemsDisplayed"
ngbDropdown
#dropdown="ngbDropdown"
[autoClose]="'outside'"
[placement]="['right-bottom', 'right', 'right-top']">
    <i ngbDropdownToggle
        class="icon icon-dots dropright drill-drop"
        [class.inactive]="isAnyActionSelected">
    </i>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu *ngIf="dropdown.isOpen()">
        <p class="drillmenuheader">{{unit.name | textEllipsis: 12 }}</p>
        <ov-drilldown-screen-item *ngFor="let drilldown of drilldowns"
            [screen]="drilldown"
            [showLabel]="true"
            (navigate)="navigate($event)">
        </ov-drilldown-screen-item>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"*ngIf="isCommandActionsVisible"></div>
        <ov-drilldown-action-item *ngFor="let action of actions"
            [action]="action"
            [showLabel]="true"
            [unitId]="unit ? unit.id : 0"
            [unitName]="unit ? unit.name : ''">
        </ov-drilldown-action-item>
    </div>
```

Angular version 7.3.1
ng-bootstrap version 4.1.3

Anyone has a solution for this issue?

thanks very much in advance :-)

Comment: Can I see the your code for that portion?

Comment: sorry, I have updated the question

Comment: Hmm.. That is strange. I tried to reproduce your code, except I am not using the `ov-drilldown-action-item` component to replicate the dropdown items. With that, the `autoClose` input with the value of `outside` seems to be working

Comment: That is strange :-| If I set it to false it isn't closing (like expected) if I set it to outside without pling ([autoClose="outside"]), then it is working like false. If I set it to outside with pling ([autoClose="'outside'"]), it closes when clicking everywhere.

Comment: puzzling indeed.. Is it possible if you can reproduce this on stackblitz? And share the link over here?